# Make vertical splitters in pure css3 in background

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a vertical splitter in background of a home-made slider (like here http://theymakeapps.com/users/add). How to do that ?
 Here is what I've done so far:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="dragger">
        <div class="rect"></div>
        <div class="arrow-down"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="slide-container"></div>
</div>
<br />
<span class="drag-caption active" id="hi-caption">Hi, bot</span>  <span class="drag-caption" id="keep-caption">Keep sliding...</span>  <span class="drag-caption" id="submit-caption">Submit</span>
```

And my css

```
* {
    font-family: calibri
}
#dragger {
    width: 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
}
.rect {
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 15px;
    width: 10px;
}
.arrow-down {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #ccc;
}
#wrapper {
    z-index: 55;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
#slide-container {
    background: #dedede;
    height:2px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    margin-top:-18px;
}
.drag-caption {
    padding-right: 20px;
    color: #d4d4d4;
    -webkit-transition: color 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: color 500ms ease;
    -ms-transition: color 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: color 500ms ease;
    transition: color 500ms ease;
}
.drag-caption.active {
    color: black;
}
#submit-caption{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

And here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/77akz/6/). I'd like my separtors to be aligned over the caption and ON the background bar.

Like this:

```
---|---------|------------|
   |         |            |
  Hi bot  Keep sliding  Submit
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've added a `div` and two `span` elements and positioned the separators on the range using CSS Positioning.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/77akz/11/)</kbd>

<kbd>[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/77akz/14/)</kbd> *(If you don't need the last one)*

<kbd>[**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/77akz/13/)</kbd> *(As per your exact requirements)*

Here, am using CSS Positioning to position each of the separator on the range bar, you can tweak up the lefts and rights according to your requirement.

```
<div id="slide-container"></div>
<div class="separators"><span></span><span></span></div> <!-- Add this after #slide-container -->

.separators {
    position: relative;
}

.separators > span:before,
.separators > span:after{
    content: "|";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    color: #DEDEDE;
}

.separators > span:nth-of-type(1):before {
    left: 50px;
    top: -12px;
}

.separators > span:nth-of-type(1):after {
    left: 100px;
    top: -12px;
}

.separators > span:nth-of-type(2):before {
    left: 150px;
    top: -12px;
}

.separators > span:nth-of-type(2):after {
    left: 200px;
    top: -12px;
}
```